# Detect Unity at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, .net-core

We have a C# library for multiple platforms and we are looking for a way to detect that it is a Unity application at runtime.

I have seen most approaches are focused on compilation directives, but that won't help because we are generating only one universal C# binary for all platforms.

Is there a straightforward way to sense that at runtime?

Answer (score 4):

You could probably evaluate the loaded assemblies via [AppDomain.GetAssemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.getassemblies?view=net-8.0)

If you find a specific assembly, that is part of Unity, you'd know that your library is loaded in an Unity-project. But you'd have to find out which Unity-assemblies are actually loaded on all platforms.

Also, I'm not 100% sure how this behaves when IL2CPP is in play, but I suppose it should still do the same thing and give you the assemblies.

Comment: Seems valid, e.g. some old version of GRPC, at some point before it dropped .net support did Unity detection same way: [some commit from 2020](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/commit/2ebd3c3c02a986a377680209e2ad9c6f10c69032)

Comment: @Renat that would be the awarded answer

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here with concrete code, as advised by @Juliean and @Renat:

```
bool isUnity = Type.GetType("UnityEngine.Application, UnityEngine") != null;
```